# Cannot use static method in BaseEntity class as serializer complains

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

All of my Entities and Documents extend a BaseObject class (it handles getId(), getClassName() and a couple of handy shortcuts).

I added a static array of traits to it - so I can iterate through these traits when adding forms and validation rules on the fly.

```
/**
 * Class BaseObject
 */
abstract class BaseObject
{
    protected $id;

    public static $traits = ['blame', 'time', 'live', 'when', 'where', 'ugc', 'security'];
...
```

However, when I try and log in I get the following error -

*Notice: serialize(): "traits" returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist in ... symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php line 149*

Should I store this list of traits elsewhere, or is there something else I should be doing here?  Some posts pointed to using the Serializable interface, but I'm not sure what the best way to use that is.

Thanks,
James

Comment: Implement [`__sleep()` / `__wakeup()`](http://php.net/__sleep) magic methods.

Comment: The issue there is that I have over 200 entities and documents and will probably be at 800 before the project is over.  I don't want to add a large array of property names to each of them (and keep it updated as the entities change).

Comment: Maybe, use a [`reflection`](http://php.net/reflection) then to not even bother? (:

Comment: I mean its probably easier just to create another class that has the traits in.  I just wanted to make sure that there's no better way around this (that doesn't require a lot of work)